# How to display data from JSON format?

Tags: json, angular, angular7

I need loop which can print data in following hierarchy solutiondetail ->  groups - > request details
The following function was giving me details of solutiondetail -> request detail. I have given both new and old json format along with working function for old json. Now after adding group detail I am facing issue with loop.

**Previous Json** : solutiondetail -> request

```
{
    "SolutionsDetail": [
        {
            "SolutionId": 658,
            "name": "dk",
            "id": 1568377327000,
            "requestDetails": [
                        {
                            "ReqId": 2331,

                        },

                    ]
        }
    ]
}

GeneartingLandingPadData(nxsolId) {
   for (let index = 0; index < this.json.length; index++) {
      if (this.array[index].SolutionId == nxsolId) {
        this.priceDetails = this.array[index].requestdetails;
             for (let k = 0; k < this.priceDetails.length; k++) {
                    console.log("some",this.priceDetails);
                }

            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**New Json** : solutiondetail ->  groups - > request details

```
 {
        "SolutionsDetail": [
            {
                "SolutionId": 658,
                "name": "dk",
                "id": 1568377327000,
                "groups": [
                    {
                        "GroupId": 1,
                        "requestDetails": [
                            {
                                "ReqId": 2331,

                            },

                        ]
                    }

                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: If this is for a template then you can just use the `json` pipe. `{{this.json | json}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the limited amount of information which you have provided, I cannot recreate the problem to test it. But from what I understood I think changing your function like below might solve your problem. With the new JSON, you have to access groups array first. Then proceed to requestId. Even if the following code doesn't exactly work hopefully you will be able to figure it out by first accessing group array and then trying for the request id.

```
GeneartingLandingPadData(nxsolId) {
       for (let index = 0; index < this.json.length; index++) {
          if (this.array[index].SolutionId == nxsolId) {
            var groupDetails = this.array[index].groups;
                 for (let k = 0; k < groupDetails.length; k++) {
                     var priceDetails = groupDetails[k].requestDetails;
                     for (let j = 0; j < priceDetails.length; j++){
                         console.log("some", priceDetails);
                     }
                 }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks your answer helped me for further development.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking to print the data in console, I am assuming that you'd need the whole row for each request detail

> solutiondetail -> groups - > request details

relevant **TS**:

```
  GeneartingLandingPadData(nxsolId) {
    for (let index = 0; index < this.newJson.SolutionsDetail.length; index++) {
      if (this.newJson.SolutionsDetail[index].SolutionId == nxsolId) {
        for (let j = 0; j < this.newJson.SolutionsDetail[index].groups.length; j++) {
          for (let k = 0; k < this.newJson.SolutionsDetail[index].groups[j].requestDetails.length; k++) {

            console.log("solutiondetail :", this.newJson.SolutionsDetail[index].name, " -> Groups:", this.newJson.SolutionsDetail[index].groups[j].GroupId, " -> Request detail:", this.newJson.SolutionsDetail[index].groups[j].requestDetails[k].ReqId);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly: you want to transform the old JSON into a new one. So, the **map()** method is the best way to transform arrays and by this way - transform your JSON. Here is one more version made with TypeScript that allows you to escape the deep nesting of the **for loop**,
where we take an old JSON and transform its 'SolutionsDetail' array. Maybe it helps you too.

Working sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ryrvw

The method below returns a new JSON:

```
  GeneartingLandingPadData(oldJson: any): any {
     return oldJson['SolutionsDetail'].map((sDetail: any) => {
        let groups: Array<any> = [];
        sDetail['requestDetails'].forEach((details: any, index: number) => {
           groups.push({ GroupId: index + 1, requestDetails: [details] });
        });
        delete sDetail['requestDetails'];
        sDetail['groups'] = groups;
        return sDetail;
     });
  }
```

**Old JSON**

```
  {
     "SolutionsDetail": [
        {
           "SolutionId": 658,
           "name": "dk",
           "id": 1568377327000,
           "requestDetails": [
              {
                 "ReqId": 2331,
              },
           ]
        }
     ]
  }
```

**New JSON**

```
  {
     "SolutionsDetail": [
        {
           "SolutionId": 658,
           "name": "dk",
           "id": 1568377327000,
           "groups": [
              {
                 "GroupId": 1,
                 "requestDetails": [
                    {
                       "ReqId": 2331,
                    },
                 ]
              }
           ]
        }
     ]
  }
```

Works for me) Good luck.

Comment: Instead of pasting a code sample, you should explain what your code sample actually does such that the OP and others can understand what you've done to fix the problem.

Comment: Updated the description) Thanks